# Why is my Python code not using the .replace function correctly?

Tags: python, replace, str-replace, numerical-integration

I am trying to write a program for a numerical integrator.  Omitting all of the steps which I know I have correct, here is what I have that is not working:

```
fcn = str(input("Enter your function in terms of x: "))
a = eval(input('Enter a: '))
b = eval(input('Enter b: '))
N = 10
for i in range(1,N):
        x = str(fcn.find('x'))
        height = eval(fcn.replace(x,str(i)))
        height += height
```

However, this does not generate the correct height. For example, if I have:
fcn is x,
a is 1,
b is 10,
N is 10;
instead of getting height is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ... I get 00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00.

I'm very much a beginner in Python. I know that I have a lot of eval and str functions in my code, but this was just to correct errors Python kept giving me.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: If you are only using `eval` to correct other errors, working through those errors instead may be the best course of action.

Comment: `.find()` returns the index where the string is found.  So if your string is "x" and you're looking for "x", it will return zero.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Comment: @Prune - OP did provide input and expected output... granted, it could be a bit easier to read.

Comment: You don't do anything with `a` or `b`. If they are not part of this question, you can just remove them to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`find` returns the first index of "x" in the string which isn't very helpful. Instead just replace "x" with `i` and you'll cover any x's that may be in there. To make this testable, you could overwrite `input` with a function that writes canned values. In a real world environment, your code would be inside a function that itself is in an importable module and then a separate test script would mock input when called. But this will do for now.

```
# mock `input` for test
input_script = ["x + 100", "1", "10"]
def input(text):
    return input_script.pop(0)

fcn = str(input("Enter your function in terms of x: "))
a = eval(input('Enter a: '))
b = eval(input('Enter b: '))
N = 10
for i in range(1,N):
    height = eval(fcn.replace("x", str(i)))
    print(height)
```